# Django url app namespacing conflicts

Tags: python, django

I have a Django site with two apps.  One is an api and the other is a frontend.  For some reason the urls for the frontend are resolving to the api...

game_server/games/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from api import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^$', views.index, name = 'index'),
        url(r'^tictactoe/$', views.tictactoe, name = 'tictactoe'),
)
```

game_server/api/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from api import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^$', views.index, name = 'index'),
        url(r'^tictactoe/$', views.tictactoe, name = 'tictactoe'),
)
```

game_server/game_server/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^games/', include('games.urls', namespace="games", app_name="games")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^api/', include('api.urls', namespace="api", app_name="api"))
)
```

But whenever I visit 127.0.0.1:8000/games/tictactoe, it gives me the tictactoe view from game_server/api/views.py (and similarly for the index)

I'm sure it's something obvious, but I think I followed the process in the Django polls app pretty much identically...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `games/urls.py` you have:

```
from api import views
```

You want to import the `games` views instead:

```
from games import views
```